# Comments not exported from PDF with python modules PyMuPDF and PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf, pymupdf

I tried to export all annotations of some pdf files including comments (meaning not highlighted text, but commented text I added). The highlights will export just fine, but my own remarks/comments won't. What am I doing wrong?

E.g.:
[image: annotated pdf]
[image: exported text file]

I tried to user PyPDF2 and PyMuPDF.

MWE for PyPDF2

```
import os
import PyPDF2

def check_pdf_comments(pdf_file):
    try:
        with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as pdf_file:
            pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
            for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
                page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
                if '/Annots' in page:
                    return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"error on file {pdf_file}: {str(e)}")
    return False

def main():
    folder_path = '/path-to-my-pdfs/'
    matching_files = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.pdf'):
                pdf_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                if check_pdf_comments(pdf_file):
                    matching_files.append(pdf_file)

    output_file_path = '/desired-outputpath/matching_files.txt'
    with open(output_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        for pdf_file in matching_files:
            output_file.write(pdf_file + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

MWE for PyMuPDF / fitz

```
import os
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

def extract_annotations_and_highlights(pdf_file):
    annotations_and_highlights = []
    try:
        doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
        for page_num in range(len(doc)):
            page = doc.load_page(page_num)
            annotations = page.annots()
            for annot in annotations:
                if 1 <= annot.type[0] <= 12:  # Include annotation types 1 through 12
                    text = page.get_text("text", clip=annot.rect)
                    page_number = page_num + 1  # Page numbers are 1-based
                    annotations_and_highlights.append((page_number, text))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error for {pdf_file}: {str(e)}")
    return annotations_and_highlights

def main():
    folder_path = '/folder-path-name/'
    desktop_path = '/desktop-path/'
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.pdf'):
                pdf_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                annotations_and_highlights = extract_annotations_and_highlights(pdf_file)
                if annotations_and_highlights:
                    # Create the output file path on the desktop
                    output_text_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + "_annotations.txt")
                    with open(output_text_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
                        for page_number, text in annotations_and_highlights:
                            output_file.write(f"Page Number: {page_number}\n")
                            output_file.write(f"Text: {text}\n\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your "own comments" are so-called FreeText annotations. In PyMuPDF, their text is contained in `annot.info["content"]`. So best store the annot rectangle and that text in your list for reproduction in the target page.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out comments were included in
`annot.info["content"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can read annotations with `pypdf` (PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf instead): https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/reading-pdf-annotations.html

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("commented.pdf")

for page in reader.pages:
    if "/Annots" in page:
        for annot in page["/Annots"]:
            obj = annot.get_object()
            # The `/Contents` key is interesting for the /Subtype /FreeText
            print(obj)
```